# AngularJS filter exact match except for free text search

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

AngularJS docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) have a very clear example how to use their filter together with a comparator so that you can do exact match by setting :true on the filter

```
ng-repeat="task in tasks  | filter:search:true
```

The problem is that i am searching on the search object (as per their example) and one of the search filters is a free text search.
How can i get the strict search to apply to my other search filters but NOT to my free text search.

So to stick with their example. Looking at the following

```
<label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
<label>Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"></label><br>
```

How can I get strict filtering to apply to search.name and search.phone but NOT to search.$

Note: In my code I dont have search.name and search.phone as text inputs but rather as dropdown selections which is why i want them to be strict.

Please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apply several filters:

  ng-repeat="task in tasks  | filter:{'$' : search.$} | filter:{'phone' : search.phone}:true | filter:{'name' : search.phone}:true
- Make your own filter:

  ng-repeat="task in tasks  | myfilter:search
  app.filter('myfilter')

Comment: Great. Didnt know you could chain them like that. Is there a syntax to say something like this
ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:{'$' : search.$} | filter::true
So that it will do non-strict on $ but strict on everything else without listing them?